# create table to compare rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In order to be able to use UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY in oracle, i would need to have a table(temp table in my case) in following format

a ----------------abc

a ----------------bax

a ----------------tax

b ----------------abc

b ----------------bax

b ----------------tax

c ----------------abc

c ----------------bax

c ----------------tax

I have column in the LEFT coming from one table and the column in RIGHT from another table. My question is how to create table in such format?

I would highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you need a temp table? The jaro_winkler_similarity is just a function - you can call it with any string values.

Comment: I wanted to create a temp table for convenience since two columns that i am comparing are from two different tables.

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want empty structure then:

```
create table test as 
  select table1.col1, table2.col2
    from table1, table2
    where 1=0
```

If you want table with data then:

```
create table test as 
  select distinct table1.col1, table2.col2
    from table1, table2
```